# SQL witness unavailable, principal and mirror disconnected / in recovery

Tags: sql-server, database-mirroring

We've had some network issues causing the witness SQL instance to be unavailable. The principal and mirror are both now showing as 'Disconnected / In Recovery'. Is this the expected behaviour when using a witness? Or should the principal and mirror be connected and synchronised without automatic fail-over due to the witness being unavailable?

I've tried the following to make the principal accessible:
- Restarted the SQL instance
- Restarted the end point

I'd appreciate any insight into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could have come into this issue:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2490051

We had this in case of (likely) network failures without conditions described in KB on SQL Server 2008 (10.0.6000)

Check your network connection, try to drop and recreate endpoints. 
If you just want to bring DB online, issue ALTER DATABASE Your_DB_Name SET PARTNER OFF.
Also you can reconfigure your mirror, it should not lead to any data loss.

Answer (score 0):

The principal database is Disconnected and in Recovery, if the steps here: [https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2490051][1] didn't help, below are the steps to get the database online and available again.

--STEP 1 ON PRINCIPAL, break the mirror for a database

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2016 SET PARTNER OFF;
```

--STEP 2 ON PRINCIPAL, recover the database and make it available

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2016 WITH RECOVERY;
```

--STEP 3 ON MIRROR, break the mirror for a database

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorks2016 SET PARTNER OFF;
```

at the end of this 3 steps you have a database on the principal server online and available with no mirror and one database on the mirror server in restoring with no mirror.
If step 2 doesn't succeed, read the error message carefully and take the next step accordingly; However, it is more likely that you might end up restoring the database from your last backup (full+tran)

Note. I wouldn't recover the database on the mirror server, in fact, it should be deleted (to avoid any confusion) or left in restoring for a future reconfiguration as mirror database.